# Erb: How to make a block repeat horizontally?

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, erb

If I have a block of the following format:

```
<% @model.each do |f| %>
  <%= f.name %>
  <%= image_tag("some_picture.jpg") %>
  <br>
<% end %>
```

How do I get it to repeat itself horizontally, instead of vertically? If the list is long enough to reach the end of its containing div, I would like for it to continue a line down, like normal html text.

Comment: Than just remove the line with the `<br>`. It unvalid ERB anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This concatenates the names array using [Array#join](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.4/Array.html#method-i-join) with a single space between them:

```
<%= @model.map(&:name).join(' ') %>
```

Wrapping this within a paragraph element would give you what you are looking for:

```
<%= content_tag(:p, @model.map(&:name).join(' ')) %>
```

Comment: Could I do that if the block contained an image as well?

Comment: Sure the syntax would be a little different depending on what you're trying to do.  But yes you can definitely have images as well.  Take a look into `image_tag`.